# Snackbar isn't shown after onResume(), but it got called

Tags: java, android, onresume, snackbar

My Snackbar is always shown if the Phone is not connected to the Internet:

```
public class NetworkListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SnackbarInterface snbInterface;

    public NetworkListener(SnackbarInterface snbInterface) {
        this.snbInterface = snbInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (ni == null || !ni.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            snbInterface.ToggleSnackbar(true);
        }
        else if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {
            snbInterface.ToggleSnackbar(false);
        }
    }

    public interface SnackbarInterface {
        public void ToggleSnackbar(boolean ShowHide);
    }
}
```

Here's my Method from MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void ToggleSnackbar(boolean ShowHide) {
    bOnline = ShowHide;

    if (ShowHide) snbNoInternet.show();
    else snbNoInternet.dismiss();
}
```

And my Snackbar:

```
snbNoInternet = Snackbar.make(listView, R.string.snb_NoInternet, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
snbNoInternet.setAction(R.string.snba_OpenSettings, new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS));
    }
});
```

I'm sure that the Snackbar is called! (Tested it)

It works if I set the Snackbar to "null" in onPause() and initialise it again in onResume().

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Are you calling .show() method? I dont see.

Comment: Yes, I'm calling: Look at ToggleSnackbar() -> if (ShowHide) snbNoInternet.show();

Comment: Oh my bad, I did not see that awful if-else (lol). Try this: snbNoInternet = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), R.string.snb_NoInternet, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);

Comment: I tried: My FloatingActionButton is hidden behind the Snackbar and it doesn't work...